# Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So Im following this tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMiggUPst-Q&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=2) and I seem to have made an error somewhere.

Full Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Util.checkGLError(Util.java:59)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.java:1205)
    at renderEngine.Renderer.render(Renderer.java:21)
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:33)
```

Code:

Renderer.java:

```
package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import renderEngine.RawModel;

public class Renderer {

    public void prepare() {

        GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    }

    public void render(RawModel model) {

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE, 0, model.getVertexCount());
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

}
```

RawModel.java

```
package renderEngine;

public class RawModel {

    private int vaoID;
    private int vertexCount;

    public RawModel(int vaoID, int vertexCount) {

        this.vaoID = vaoID;
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount;

    }

    public int getVaoID() {

        return vaoID;

    }

    public int getVertexCount() {

        return vertexCount;

    }

}
```

MainGameLoop.java:

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import renderEngine.DisplayManager;
import renderEngine.Loader;
import renderEngine.RawModel;
import renderEngine.Renderer;

public class MainGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DisplayManager.createDisplay();

    Loader loader = new Loader();
    Renderer renderer = new Renderer(); 

    float[] vertices = {

            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f

    };

    RawModel model = loader.loadToVao(vertices);

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        renderer.prepare();
        renderer.render(model);
        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
    }

    loader.cleanUp();

    DisplayManager.closeDisplay();

  }

}
```

DisplayManager.java:

```
package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

public class DisplayManager {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
    private static final int FPSCAP = 120;

    public static void createDisplay() {

        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
            Display.setTitle("Game");
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      }

    public static void updateDisplay() {

        Display.sync(FPSCAP);
        Display.update();

    }

    public static void closeDisplay() {

        Display.destroy();

    }

}
```

Loader.java:

```
package renderEngine;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

public class Loader {

    private List<Integer> vaos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public RawModel loadToVao(float[] positions) {

        int vaoID = createVAO();
        storeDataInAttributeList(0,positions);
        unbindVAO();
        return new RawModel(vaoID,positions.length/3);

    }

    public void cleanUp() {

        for(int vao:vaos) {

            GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);

        }
        for(int vbo:vbos) {

            GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vbo);

        }

    }

    private int createVAO() {

        int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        vaos.add(vaoID);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        return vaoID;

    }

    private void storeDataInAttributeList(int attributeNumber, float[] data) {

        int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNumber, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }

    private void unbindVAO() {

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

    private FloatBuffer storeDataInFloatBuffer(float[] data) {

        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;

    }

}
```

I do see that it is telling me that something is wrong in the renderer file at line 21 and it ran into the error while performing MainGameLoop line 33

But other than that, I cant figure it out.

I am using Java SDK 8
LWJGL 2.8.9 (or something like that)

Comment: Where is you shader program? You use a [core profile context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#OpenGL_3.2_and_Profiles) with [forward compatibility](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Forward_compatibility) flag `true`. You have to use [shader program](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader), it is not optional. Use a compatibility profile or change the forward compatibility flag if you don't have a shader program.

Comment: I removed the profile and forward compat but now I get
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
 at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenVertexArrays(GL30.java:1633)
 at renderEngine.Loader.createVAO(Loader.java:35)
 at renderEngine.Loader.loadToVAO(Loader.java:19)
 at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:29)`

Comment: Well, looks like you do not have support for GL 3.0. Note there are a coiuple of platforms and implementations which support only GL >= 3.2 in **core profile**, or legacy GL up to 2.1. The correct solution to your issue also isn't to switch back to legacy GL, but to add shaders.